# How do I setup filehelpers with a required, not empty column

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I've been looking through filehelpers documentation, but there doesn't seem anything to handle empty values in columns.  I need to be able to set a 'non-empty' string attribute on all the columns.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question is rather vague: How are you defining your FileHelpers record class?  Are you trying to import or export?  Are all your columns strings or are some of them integers, dates, etc.?

Comment: Yes I'm defining the record class.  I'm trying to import into strings, which by default are nullable.  I think that is the problem. FileHelpers doesn't have validation on empty values for strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform any validation you want in the `AfterReadRecord` event.  If you want to continue processing the rest of the file if there is an error, you also need to set the `ErrorMode` to `SaveAndContinue`.  See below for a working example.

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<MyClass>();
        engine.AfterReadRecord += new FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadHandler<MyClass>(engine_AfterReadRecord);
        engine.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
        // import a record with an invalid Email
        MyClass[] validRecords = engine.ReadString("Hello||World");
        ErrorInfo[] errors = engine.ErrorManager.Errors;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, engine.TotalRecords); // 1 record was processed
        Assert.AreEqual(0, validRecords.Length); // 0 records were valid
        Assert.AreEqual(1, engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount); // 1 error was found
        Assert.That(errors[0].ExceptionInfo.Message == "Field2 is invalid");
    }

    static void engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, FileHelpers.Events.AfterReadEventArgs<MyClass> e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record.Field1))
            throw new Exception("Field1 is invalid");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record.Field2))
            throw new Exception("Field2 is invalid");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record.Field3))
            throw new Exception("Field3 is invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've actually decided to store the valid rows from the 1st pass, and then carry my own validation on the populated class record itself, although I might go the route you suggested. Thanks for the help. Do you know where I can submit bugs to this library? I've found a bug and I'd like to send a patch (thought there might be github/bitbucket stored repo).

Comment: Another solution would be to set `e.SkipThisRecord = true` in the `AfterReadRecord` event which just ignores the line instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

By default an empty string will be parsed as `String.Empty` in FileHelpers, but you can override this with a custom converter:

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string sourceString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceString))
            return null;
        return sourceString;
    }
}
```

Then you define your record class property like this

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(EmptyStringConverter))]
public string Field1;
```

If the string corresponding to `Field1` is empty or blank, it will be converted to null.

Comment: I need this to cause an error on the row, so I could just throw an exception then?

Comment: I see - you want to perform validation on the field and reject the record if it is null - that was not clear form your question.  I'll add another answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out with empty strings being saved as "" in the DB, they're now saving as NULL.  Future note for ppl looking at this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Converter will not work, as `FileHelpers.FieldBase` checks for a zero length field, and returns Null, before invoking the Converter.

Using the `public static FileHelperEngine GetEngine()` ensures that the `AfterReadRecord` event validation is wired up correctly.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class RequiredField
{
    public string Required;

    public static FileHelperEngine GetEngine()
    {
        var result = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(RequiredField));
        result.AfterReadRecord += AfterReadValidation;

        return result;
    }

    private static void AfterReadValidation(EngineBase sender, AfterReadRecordEventArgs args)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((RequiredField)args.Record).Required))
        {
            throw new ConvertException("RequiredField is Null or WhiteSpace", typeof(String));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing for one of our projects that utilizes FileHelpers heavily and contributed to provide the new [FieldNotEmptyAttribute](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/commit/c0ac00af7cb9bcd50a5313ae590ea42dd50a6c7c), which could be used like so:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class MyClass
{
    [FieldNotEmpty()]
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
    [FieldNotEmpty()]
    public string Field3;
}
```

In the example above, if Field1 or Field3 is empty in the source file, then a [ConvertException](http://filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.ConvertException.html) is thrown.